# validation for \n & \r in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi I want to do validation on text box for( where,`\n,\r`). I tried with following code but its not working for `\n` and `\r`. and same if I give alert `\n` will change into `<br>` and not showing that `\n` is not allowed.

JavaScript:

```
function val() {
    var et=document.getElementById('plcyWhrclausNm').value;
    alert(et)
    if (et.indexOf('\r') > 0|| et.indexOf('\n') > 0|| et.indexOf('where') >= 0) {
        alert('where or "\n" not allowed');
        return false;
    }
```

JSP code:

```
<html:textarea property="plcyWhrclausNm" cols="55" rows="2" onblur="val()"></html:textarea>
```

Comment: How is it "now working"? It doesn't validate? You're getting errors? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, escape the `\n` in your alert: `'where or "\\n" not allowed'`.

Comment: `\n` and `\r` are translated to control characters LF and CR. Is that what you're really looking for, or the actual text containing backslash followed by `n` or `r`?

Comment: It working fine http://jsfiddle.net/jQqs7/1/  .